# Two Columns with Delimiter into Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'll start out by saying this answer is very similar. I'll apologize ahead of time if that is the true solution to my problem.

[Combining two sql columns with delimited data by collating into a single column with delimited data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655510/combining-two-sql-columns-with-delimited-data-by-collating-into-a-single-column#answer-55656036)

I have a table in an Oracle database with two columns that have delimited values separated with pipes (|). The values in these columns correspond to each other. Meaning the first value before the pipe in col1 is related to the first value before the pipe in col2. Here is the sample data:

| key | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678|87654321 | ABABABAB|CDCDCDCD |
| 2 | 12345678|87654321 | ABABABAB|EFEFEFEF |
| 3 | 12345678|11223344 | ABABABAB|ZXZXZXZX |
| 4 | 12345678|11223344 | ABABABAB|ZXZXZXZX |

I need these columns split into rows and have the corresponding data in the same row like this:

| key | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 | ABABABAB |
| 1 | 87654321 | CDCDCDCD |
| 2 | 12345678 | ABABABAB |
| 2 | 87654321 | EFEFEFEF |
| 3 | 12345678 | ABABABAB |
| 3 | 11223344 | ZXZXZXZX |
| 4 | 12345678 | ABABABAB |
| 4 | 11223344 | ZXZXZXZX |

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to get rid of this horrible table and replace it with a normalized one? That is a very good idea. Gordon's recursive query should work for you. Remove his `and lev < 5` in order not to limit the number of possible entries in a row. You don't need it. You can `create table new_table as with cte ...` to create the new table from the query.

Comment: Thorsten, thank you for the comment. Do you have any idea why I would be downvoted for this question? I know there was a similar question, but it wasn't efficient and didn't seem to work for my scenario. And, by the way the data in question is from a vehicle, not poor table design. The data that comes back can be in various formats.

Comment: It happens from time to time that people downvote a request or an answer without leaving a comment as to the whys, which leaves us completely clueless. Maybe someone thought that you didn't put enough effort in this yourself. You have linked to a request for another DBMS with a solution including a function `STRING_SPLIT` that doesn't even exist in Oracle. There is no indication that you tried to apply that query or any query for that matter. You are interested in substrings of the original strings, but you don't even mention `SUBSTR` or other Oracle string manipulation functions.

Comment: As to the table: The database table should be normalized like the result you are after. The app that inserts the data should be resonsible for the format checking and splitting. It is possible to have both tables, the original one and the normalized one, in the database and do the conversion there. I would always prefer the first approach, though. A programming language seems more appropriate for such things anyway. You should for instance be aple to properly react to invalid input, such as col1 and col2 containing different numbers of elements.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten for your explanation. The table structure is not controlled by me. I do some data analysis for the Smog Check program in California and vehicles can sometimes have this format for their calibration identification and sometimes not. When they do this they may not have an identical number of elements for the verification number (col2). (SAE J1979.) It's a bit more complicated than what I'm showing here. I've done similar stuff with splitting a single column into multiple rows but I was a bit perplexed on how to do the two column splitting. I'll live with the downvote I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are always two values and they have the same length -- as in the data in your example -- then `union all` is a pretty simple approach:

```
select key, substr(col1, 1, 8), substr(col2, 1, 8)
from t
union all
select key, substr(col1, 10), substr(col2, 10)
from t;
```

If they don't have the same length, but there are always two values, then `regexp_substr()` is pretty convenient:

```
select key, regexp_substr(col1, '^[^|]+'), regexp_substr(col1, '[^|]+$')
from t
union all
select key, regexp_substr(col1, '^[^|]+'), regexp_substr(col1, '[^|]+$')
from t;
```

It does get more complicated if you have more values, but your sample data suggests that you have only two.

A more general method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte(key, val1, val2, rest1, rest2, lev) as (
      select key, null, null, col1 || '|', col2 || '|', 0
      from t
      union all
      select key, regexp_substr(rest1, '^[^|]+'), regexp_substr(rest2, '^[^|]+'),
             substr(rest1, instr(rest1, '|') + 1), substr(rest2, instr(rest2, '|') + 1),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest1 is not null and rest2 is not null 
     )
select key, val1, val2
from cte
where lev <> 0
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e34308bdf740ddd48a85e73dc9e706dc) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hierarchical Query with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` functions in order to split the columns such as

```
 SELECT key, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,'[^|]+',1,level) AS col1, 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(col2,'[^|]+',1,level) AS col2
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= GREATEST( REGEXP_COUNT(col1,'[|]')+1, REGEXP_COUNT(col2,'[|]')+1 )   
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR key = key
  ORDER BY key, level
```

through generating maximum number of rows for each key, depending on the fact that each of the two columns might contain same or different number of pipe characters for each row within the current set of data.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb679295b76107bc290a7ee9a533cf12)</kbd>